# Limited <selects> for second option, is querySelectorAll the right way to have multiple IDs?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to limit 'select' options for the second one, based on what is selected for the first 'select' but can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

There are two types:

**Type one is limited to 2 second  options:**

- If combo-x1 is selected, only bench-x1 is available
- If combo-x2 is selected, only bench-x1 and bench-x2 is available
- Combo-2 onwards just shows all available options

**Type two is limited to 4  options:**

- If combo-x1 is selected, only bench-x1 is available
- If combo-x2 is selected, only bench-x1 and bench-x2 is available
- If combo-x3 is selected, only bench-x1, bench-x2, bench-3 is available
- Combo-x4 onwards just shows all available options

Here is my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6yqofxhg/

HTML:

```
<div>
<br />
Set C7
</div>

<select id="C7-Drawer-Shelf-Combo">
<option value="">No Drawer/Shelf Combo</option>
<option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x1">combo-x1</option>
<option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x2">combo-x2</option>
<option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x3">combo-x3</option>
<option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x4">combo-x4</option>
</select>
     
<select id="C7-Under-Drawer-Bench">
<option value="">No Under Drawer Bench</option>
<option value="under-drawer-bench-x1">bench-x1</option>
<option value="under-drawer-bench-x2">bench-x2</option>
</select>

<div>
<br />
Set T7
</div>

<select id="T7-Drawer-Shelf-Combo">
<option value="">No Drawer/Shelf Combo</option>
<option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x1">combo-x1</option>
<option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x2">combo-x2</option>
<option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x3">combo-x3</option>
<option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x4">combo-x4</option>
</select>
     
<select id="T7-Under-Drawer-Bench">
<option value="">No Under Drawer Bench</option>
<option value="under-drawer-bench-x1">bench-x1</option>
<option value="under-drawer-bench-x2">bench-x2</option>
</select>

<div>
<br />
Set C11
</div>

<select id="C11-Drawer-Shelf-Combo">
<option value="">No Drawer/Shelf Combo</option>
<option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x1">combo-x1</option>
<option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x2">combo-x2</option>
<option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x3">combo-x3</option>
<option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x4">combo-x4</option>
</select>
     
<select id="C11-Under-Drawer-Bench">
<option value="">No Under Drawer Bench</option>
<option value="under-drawer-bench-x1">bench-x1</option>
<option value="under-drawer-bench-x2">bench-x2</option>
</select>

<div>
<br />
Set T11
</div>

<select id="T11-Drawer-Shelf-Combo">
<option value="">No Drawer/Shelf Combo</option>
<option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x1">combo-x1</option>
<option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x2">combo-x2</option>
<option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x3">combo-x3</option>
<option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x4">combo-x4</option>
</select>
     
<select id="T11-Under-Drawer-Bench">
<option value="">No Under Drawer Bench</option>
<option value="under-drawer-bench-x1">bench-x1</option>
<option value="under-drawer-bench-x2">bench-x2</option>
</select>

<div>
<br />
Set 14X
</div>

<select id="14X-Drawer-Shelf-Combo">
<option value="">No Drawer/Shelf Combo</option>
<option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x1">combo-x1</option>
<option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x2">combo-x2</option>
<option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x3">combo-x3</option>
<option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x4">combo-x4</option>
<option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x5">combo-x5</option>
<option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x6">combo-x6</option>
<option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x7">combo-x7</option>
<option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x8">combo-x8</option>
</select>
     
<select id="14X-Under-Drawer-Bench">
<option value="">No Under Drawer Bench</option>
<option value="under-drawer-bench-x1">bench-x1</option>
<option value="under-drawer-bench-x2">bench-x2</option>
<option value="under-drawer-bench-x3">bench-x3</option>
<option value="under-drawer-bench-x3">bench-x4</option>
</select>

<div>
<br />
Set 17X
</div>
    
<select id="17X-Drawer-Shelf-Combo">
<option value="">No Drawer/Shelf Combo</option>
<option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x1">combo-x1</option>
<option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x2">combo-x2</option>
<option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x3">combo-x3</option>
<option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x4">combo-x4</option>
<option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x5">combo-x5</option>
<option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x6">combo-x6</option>
<option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x7">combo-x7</option>
<option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x8">combo-x8</option>
</select>
     
<select id="17X-Under-Drawer-Bench">
<option value="">No Under Drawer Bench</option>
<option value="under-drawer-bench-x1">bench-x1</option>
<option value="under-drawer-bench-x2">bench-x2</option>
<option value="under-drawer-bench-x3">bench-x3</option>
<option value="under-drawer-bench-x3">bench-x4</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
//Two or less second options
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", e =>
{
  'use strict';

  const combo = document.querySelectorAll("#C7-Drawer-Shelf-Combo, #T7-Drawer-Shelf-Combo, #C11-Drawer-Shelf-Combo, #T11-Drawer-Shelf-Combo"),
        bench = document.querySelectorAll("#C7-Under-Drawer-Bench, #T7-Under-Drawer-Bench, #C11-Under-Drawer-Bench, #T11-Under-Drawer-Bench");

  combo.addEventListener("input", e =>
  {
    for(let i = 0; i < bench.children.length; i++)
      bench.children[i].hidden = e.target.selectedIndex < 2 && i > e.target.selectedIndex;

    if (e.target.selectedIndex && e.target.selectedIndex < 2 && bench.selectedIndex > e.target.selectedIndex)
      bench.selectedIndex = 0;
  });
});


// Four or less second select
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", e =>
{
  'use strict';

  const combo = document.querySelectorAll("14X-Drawer-Shelf-Combo, #17X-Drawer-Shelf-Combo" ),
        bench = document.querySelectorAll("14X-Under-Drawer-Bench, 17X-Under-Drawer-Bench");

  combo.addEventListener("input", e =>
  {
    for(let i = 0; i < bench.children.length; i++)
      bench.children[i].hidden = e.target.selectedIndex < 4 && i > e.target.selectedIndex;

    if (e.target.selectedIndex && e.target.selectedIndex < 4 && bench.selectedIndex > e.target.selectedIndex)
      bench.selectedIndex = 0;
  });
});
```

If someone could help me figure out what I've done wrong here/why it's not working, it would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `bench.children.length` is this not causing an error. You can simply use  `bench.length`. That will be an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use a **function** to contain the repetitive (common) tasks in JavaScript.

As an example, you need to limit *type one* to 2 options & then *type two* to 4 options. Can you notice a common task here? I hope you find it. It is limit the options in select elements. That common task needs to be executed differently by considering this information.

- Selectors
- Limit Option Count

This information we can simply pass as arguments to the function.

Then let's start coding...

Normally `ID`s we use to uniquely identify the elements & `classes` to identify generic behaviours like this. So I did a small update in HTML. That is, I create 2 classes for each type.

- Limited 2 Options

  - Combo = `.two-options-combo`
  - Bench = `.two-options-bench`
- Limited 4 Options

  - Combo = `.four-options-combo`
  - Bench = `.four-options-bench`

**HTML:**

```html
<div>
  <br />
  Set C7
</div>

<select id="C7-Drawer-Shelf-Combo" class="two-options-combo">
  <option value="">No Drawer/Shelf Combo</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x1">combo-x1</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x2">combo-x2</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x3">combo-x3</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x4">combo-x4</option>
</select>

<select id="C7-Under-Drawer-Bench" class="two-options-bench">
  <option value="" data-id="0">No Under Drawer Bench</option>
  <option value="under-drawer-bench-x1">bench-x1</option>
  <option value="under-drawer-bench-x2">bench-x2</option>
</select>

<div>
  <br />
  Set T7
</div>

<select id="T7-Drawer-Shelf-Combo" class="two-options-combo">
  <option value="">No Drawer/Shelf Combo</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x1">combo-x1</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x2">combo-x2</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x3">combo-x3</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x4">combo-x4</option>
</select>

<select id="T7-Under-Drawer-Bench" class="two-options-bench">
  <option value="">No Under Drawer Bench</option>
  <option value="under-drawer-bench-x1">bench-x1</option>
  <option value="under-drawer-bench-x2">bench-x2</option>
</select>

<div>
  <br />
  Set C11
</div>

<select id="C11-Drawer-Shelf-Combo" class="two-options-combo">
  <option value="">No Drawer/Shelf Combo</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x1">combo-x1</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x2">combo-x2</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x3">combo-x3</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x4">combo-x4</option>
</select>

<select id="C11-Under-Drawer-Bench" class="two-options-bench">
  <option value="">No Under Drawer Bench</option>
  <option value="under-drawer-bench-x1">bench-x1</option>
  <option value="under-drawer-bench-x2">bench-x2</option>
</select>

<div>
  <br />
  Set T11
</div>

<select id="T11-Drawer-Shelf-Combo" class="two-options-combo">
  <option value="">No Drawer/Shelf Combo</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x1">combo-x1</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x2">combo-x2</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x3">combo-x3</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x4">combo-x4</option>
</select>

<select id="T11-Under-Drawer-Bench" class="two-options-bench">
  <option value="">No Under Drawer Bench</option>
  <option value="under-drawer-bench-x1">bench-x1</option>
  <option value="under-drawer-bench-x2">bench-x2</option>
</select>

<div>
  <br />
  Set 14X
</div>

<select id="14X-Drawer-Shelf-Combo" class="four-options-combo">
  <option value="">No Drawer/Shelf Combo</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x1">combo-x1</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x2">combo-x2</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x3">combo-x3</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x4">combo-x4</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x5">combo-x5</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x6">combo-x6</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x7">combo-x7</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x8">combo-x8</option>
</select>

<select id="14X-Under-Drawer-Bench" class="four-options-bench">
  <option value="">No Under Drawer Bench</option>
  <option value="under-drawer-bench-x1">bench-x1</option>
  <option value="under-drawer-bench-x2">bench-x2</option>
  <option value="under-drawer-bench-x3">bench-x3</option>
  <option value="under-drawer-bench-x3">bench-x4</option>
</select>

<div>
  <br />
  Set 17X
</div>

<select id="17X-Drawer-Shelf-Combo" class="four-options-combo">
  <option value="">No Drawer/Shelf Combo</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x1">combo-x1</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x2">combo-x2</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x3">combo-x3</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x4">combo-x4</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x5">combo-x5</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x6">combo-x6</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x7">combo-x7</option>
  <option value="drawer-shelf-combo-x8">combo-x8</option>
</select>

<select id="17X-Under-Drawer-Bench" class="four-options-bench">
  <option value="">No Under Drawer Bench</option>
  <option value="under-drawer-bench-x1">bench-x1</option>
  <option value="under-drawer-bench-x2">bench-x2</option>
  <option value="under-drawer-bench-x3">bench-x3</option>
  <option value="under-drawer-bench-x3">bench-x4</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
limitOptions(".two-options-combo", ".two-options-bench", 2);
limitOptions(".four-options-combo", ".four-options-bench", 4);

function limitOptions(comboSele, benchSele, max) {
  const combo = document.querySelectorAll(comboSele); // Get all the requested combo elements
  const bench = document.querySelectorAll(benchSele); // Get all the requested bench elements

  // Loop through the combo select elements
  combo.forEach((item, key) => {
    // Listen to change event of them
    item.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
      const id = item.selectedOptions[0].index; // Get index of the selected option in specific combo
      const benchOpts = bench[key].options; // Get the relevent bench options by considering the key of the combo
      const limit = id <= max ? id : benchOpts.length; // Check whether that index is below or equal to the max

      // Loop through the bench options
      Object.values(benchOpts).forEach((option, index) => {
        index <= limit
          ? option.removeAttribute("hidden")
          : option.setAttribute("hidden", "true");
      });
    });
  });
}
```

**Note** - You can execute functions in `window.onload` or any other related one.

https://codesandbox.io/s/limit-options-67996460-6465v?file=/src/index.js

Let me know if you need further support.

Comment: This works so great, thank you! Only thing I noticed is when you first load the page, if you go straight to the bench options select, the two/four options are available. There should be none available, if the first select is at none as well. Is there a way to set this as well?